# Joining two tables and create virtual columns by their type

Tags: mysql, join, merge

I am currently developing some kind of calendar for scholar exams. Because of the calendar being very slow at the moment, I wanted to enhance the MySQL behind it.
I've read about JOINs and tried to used them in order to directly get the results I need but I am currently stuck at a problem.

I have two tables (simplified)

```
DAYS                           EVENTS
id | date                      id | day_id | class | text
1  | 2016-02-05                1  | 1      | a     | Example
2  | 2016-02-06                2  | 1      | b     | Example for Class b
etc.
```

Now, *I'd like to* receive the following result if I select a day:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [date] => 2016-01-25
        [a] => 1 (ID of the Event on that day with the class 'a')
        [b] => 2 (ID of the Event on that day with the class 'b')
        [c] => NULL
    )
```

But my query I created as far does not merge the results:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [date] => 2016-02-05
        [a] => 13
        [b] => 
        [c] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 11
        [date] => 2016-02-05
        [a] => 
        [b] => 14
        [c] => 
    )
```

How can I achvieve the two results being merged? My query looks like this:

```
SELECT d.*, 
     CASE WHEN e.class = 'a' THEN e.id ELSE NULL END AS a,
     CASE WHEN e.class = 'b' THEN e.id ELSE NULL END AS b,
     CASE WHEN e.class = 'c' THEN e.id ELSE NULL END AS c
  FROM examplan_days d
      LEFT JOIN examplan_events e ON d.id = e.day_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want aggregation:

```
SELECT d.*, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN e.class = 'a' THEN e.id END) AS a,
       MAX(CASE WHEN e.class = 'b' THEN e.id END) AS b,
       MAX(CASE WHEN e.class = 'c' THEN e.id END) AS c
FROM examplan_days d LEFT JOIN
     examplan_events e
     ON d.id = e.day_id
GROUP BY d.id;
```

If you can have more than one class on a given day, then you should use `GROUP_CONCAT()` rather than `MAX()`.

Comment: There is always just one entry for a class on a day. 
And the grouping does not work, it returns just the result of class a, although there should be values for a, b and c

Comment: Take his query and change the group by to group by d.date

Comment: Unfortunately does not work either, same problem as described above.
// edit: Just forgot the MAX function, thanks. It works

Comment: @Giraffe . . . What is in the other two columns?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Which columns exactly?

Comment: @Giraffe . . . This adds three columns, `a`, `b`, and `c`.  These should have the three classes you want.